# Remove suggestion after comma on Sublime-text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext4

I need help to remove the suggestion after comma on Sublime-text

Usually when I write a comma (,) I obtain this:
[Sublime suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioAbs.png)

but I don't need this suggestion, usually I'd like to go to new line or add another signal after the comma.

On the net I have see that same people have this problem after import SublimeIntel package, but I don't have it, my Package are: SystemVerilog, Verilog and VHDL.

Has anyone managed to remove the suggestion?

I have try to add same setting as:
"ignored_snippets": [","]
"auto_complete_commit_on_enter": false
but the situation remains the same.